# Best Practice for retrieving and iterating over one to many

Tags: jstl, javabeans

I'm trying to produce a web page report of Orders Per Customer with line item details for each order.
So it looks like this:

```
Customer 1  | Order 1  |     Item 1    |
            |          | == New Row == |
            |          |     Item 2    |                     
            |          | == New Row == |
            |          |     Item 3    |                     
            |          | == New Row == |
            | ====== New Row ========= |
            | Order 2  |     Item 1    |                     
            |          | == New Row == |
            |          |     Item 2    |                     
            |          | == New Row == |
            |          |     Item 3    |                     
            |          | == New Row == |
            | ====== New Row ========= |
            | Order 3  |     Item 1    |                     
            |          |     Item 2    |
== New Row ==============================                     
Customer 2  | Order 1  |     Item 1    |                     
            |          | == New Row == |
            |          |     Item 2    |                     
            |          | == New Row == |
            |          |     Item 3    |                     
            |          | == New Row == |
            |          |     Item 4    |                     
            |          | == New Row == |
            |          |     Item 5    |                     
            |          | == New Row == |
            | ====== New Row ========= |
            | Order 2  |     Item 1    |                     
            |          | == New Row == |
            |          |     Item 2    |                     
            |          | == New Row == |
            |          |     Item 3    |                     
== New Row ==============================
```

Is it better to get an array list of data as follows:

```
1  | 1 |  1 |                     
1  | 1 |  2 |                     
1  | 1 |  3 |                     
1  | 2 |  1 |                     
1  | 2 |  2 |                     
1  | 2 |  3 |                     
1  | 3 |  1 |                     
1  | 3 |  2 |                     
2  | 1 |  1 |                     
2  | 1 |  2 |                     
2  | 1 |  3 |                     
2  | 1 |  4 |                     
2  | 1 |  5 |                     
2  | 2 |  1 |                     
2  | 2 |  2 |                     
2  | 2 |  3 |
```

and pass 1 JavaBean and use JSTL to determine the nesting as follows:

```
  this is incomplete for brevity
  <table><tr><th>Customer No</th><th>Orders</th></tr>
  <c:forEach var="custOrderLineItem" items="${customerOrderLineItemList}">
  <c:set var="currentOrder" value="custOrderLineItem.orderId">
  <c:set var="currentCustomer" value="custOrderLineItem.customerId">

  <c:if test="${currentOrder != custOrderLineItem.orderId}">
      ==New Row==
  </c:if>
```

or is it better to use nested JavaBeans

```
Customer.setOrders<List>
Orders.setOrderDetails<List>
OrderDetails.setLineItem<List>
```

and then use JSTL as such

```
      <c:forEach var="customer" items="${customerList}">
         <c:forEach var="order" items="${customer.orderList}">
             <c:forEach var="lineItem" items="${order.detailList}">
```

After spending the time writing this, I feel like the second method looks cleaner and easier.  But the first method seems to have an easier SQL query.  I'm not using JPA, just basic JDBC sql calls. So how does one populate nested JavaBeans, without JPA?  Do you do something like this?

```
  List<Customer> custList = getCustomerList();
  ListIterator custListIter = custList.listIterator();
     while (custListIter.hasNext()) {
         customer = (Customer) custListIter.next();
         List<Order> orderList = getOrderList(customer.getId());
         ListIterator orderListIter = orderList.listIterator();
        while (orderListIter.hasNext()) {
                 order = (Order) orderListIter.next();
                 List orderDetailsList<OrderDetail> = getOrderDetailList(order.getId);
                 order.setOrderDetails(orderDetailsList);
                 orderListIter.set(order);
             }
         customer.setOrderList(orderList);
         custListIter.set(customer);
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply make the SQL query which returns everything, and build the graph of objects from the result set. Using maps to keep an association between IDs and the corresponding objects:

```
Map<Long, Customer> customersById = new HashMap<Long, Customer>();
Map<Long, Order> ordersById = new HashMap<Long, Order>();
Map<Long, Item> itemsById = new HashMap<Long, Item>();
while (rs.next()) {
    Long customerId = rs.getLong(1);
    Customer customer = customersById.get(customerId);
    if (customer == null) {
        customer = new Customer(customerId);
        // populate other fields of customer
        customersById.put(customerId, customer);
    }

    Long orderId = rs.getLong(5);
    Order order = ordersById.get(orderId);
    if (order == null) {
        order = new Order(orderId);
        customer.addOrder(order);
        // populate other fields of order
        ordersById.put(orderId, order);
    }

    // same for items

}
```

At the end of the loop, you have all the customers, each with their orders, each with their items.

Comment: hmm, interesting.  I don't use Maps enough.   Is customer.addOrder adding orders to a List or another Map?  In my Customer JavaBean I had setOrderList and it was setting one big list.

Comment: To any structure you want. A list would make sense if you need to preserve insertion order (for example if your query sorts by product name, then order name, then item name, for example).

Comment: I'm almost there but am I wondering if the only way now get each object is to use 'value' as in ${customer.value.orderList}?  I was hoping to use just ${customer.orderList}

Comment: I don't see why the value field would be needed.If you have a `getOrderList()` method in the Customer class, you just need `${customer.orderList}`

Comment: I do have a getOrderList().  But in the Dao, I was returning customerById, which is a Map. My fix, while probably wrong, was to add customerList.addAll(customerById.values()) right after the While (rs.next()) {} and then returned customerList<List>. In my jsp I have <c:forEach var="customer" items="${customerList}"> and then ${customer.orderList} works without the value field.

Comment: your method seems to be working but like I mentioned in my comment above, I had to create a cutomerList and return that.  Does it make sense to have had to do that? I was hoping to hear back on my comment above, either way I accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Your model should not depend on the way you retrieve informations from the database. Design the model as you want it to be, and implment the appropriate method to populate it. Once you have the maps thanks to the above answer, you have everything you need to populate your model.